# Label in gridview changes but change does not postback

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a gridview with a label, along with some JavaScript and jQuery to make the label editable.

However, when I postback and debug in my code behind I do not see the change.

How can I make it so I can get the change on the server?

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvGroups" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
 CssClass="table table-hover table-striped" GridLines="None" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="GroupDescription">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblName" CssClass="edit" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("GroupDescription") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

function makeLabelsEditable() {

    $(".edit").focusout(function () {
        setLabel(this);
    });

    $(".edit").click(function () {
        editLabel(this);
    });
}

function editLabel(source) {
    source.innerHTML = '<input type="text" maxlength="40" value="' + source.innerHTML + '"/>';
    $(source).unbind('click');
    source.children[0].focus()
}
function setLabel(source) {    
    if (source.children[0].value != '') {
        $(source).click(function () {
            editLabel(this);
        });
        source.innerHTML = source.children[0].value;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Label` will not postback to the server.  They are intended to be readonly and render as a span.  If you want it to post back the easiest thing to do is make a `Hidden` control with the same value and when you do you code to allow editting to a label, you make sure to write the editted value to the `Hidden`.  The `Hidden` will be posted back to the server and then you can read the value.

You are swapping in a 'dynamic' `TextBox` so the server has no clue about the input control you made.  You could read the raw posted params to get the value probably but it would be just easier to have a static control that you can write to and know it will have the value you need.

Comment: How can I do this dynamically? Currently I do it based on if a label has the edit class.

Comment: @user2043533 add a `Hidden` control to your template for each row.  When you write to the textbox (leave focus or something), just make sure the value gets copied into the `Hidden`.  It's a little convoluted but what you are doing doesn't seem really standard anyways.  Not sure why you are not just using an `EditTemplate` in your `GridView`.

Comment: With the EditTemplate how could I switch from Edit to non edit mode when I click on the label then exit when the textbox loses focus:?

Comment: @user2043533 Typically you would have a button that puts it in 'Edit' mode but you could probably simulate the 'Edit' button with a LinkButton and or something and style it to look like the `Label`.  Honestly though, unless you have requirement for it to act exactly as you described I would rethink it a bit and just use the standard edit method.

Comment: Is there a way I can edit without posting back right away, I only want to postback when I click another button.

Comment: @user204353 Do what you are doiong now but add a `Hidden` field like I suggested to your `ItemTemplate`. `OnKeyPress` or whatever, make sure you are copying the text from the textbox to the `Hidden` field.  Not sure there is more help I can offer without doing it for you.

Comment: @Kelsey - You said `Label will not postback to the server`. If so, how you are getting its value in server side on postback? am I missing something? please clarify.

Comment: @user204353 I have also noticed that you post questions but never accept / upvote anything.  You should reward the people that are trying to help you and also signify what answer was the most helpful to your question so that the next person that has the same problem can find the answer quickly as well.

Comment: @NaveenBhat read my answer and the comments here.  The `Hidden` field or a `TextBox` will post the value back.

Comment: @Kelsey - I understand your explanation and the work around which you told is reasonable, but I don't agree with your first sentence `Label will not postback to the server`.

Comment: @NaveenBhat if you disagree, posting why would help. Chat would probably be a better format for that. Nothing you do to a `Label` will postback the changes made to it as it renders as a `span`.  Not sure what there is to disagree with but maybe there is something I am missing.

Comment: Well, according to my understanding, everything in the page will be posted-back to the server. Hence Label also will be posted back to the server. I just wanted to point out that your sentence might misguide the reader.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make changes on the server in this way. You just change html on the client side

Answer (score 0):

The `ViewState` will not be generated for the label in client side, since it is intended to be read only. Hence, you are getting same value in the post-back which you set in the server earlier.

The easiest workaround what I can think of is:

- Place a TextBox instead of label.
- Apply a css class to it so that it look like a Label.
- On click of the TextBox, remove the css.

You can apply the css back whenever you want to give the label look.

Comment: I think your understanding is incorrect or at least we might be thinking of the same thing but differently.  A `Label` does produce `ViewState`, try applying a color to it or something in server side code with `ViewState` on and you will see that it will be preserved between PostBacks.  The difference that we are talking about is the rendered control (output) which is a span, will NOT postback anything.  It is no different than a typical span so ASP.NET knows nothing about it.  Typically I use `Literal` controls everywhere instead of `Label` to avoid the `ViewState` overhead.